# DocuSign: setting user permissions using REST APIs

Tags: rest, docusignapi

For creating a group, a user and assigning the user to that group, I referred this link [Add permission profile through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409781/add-permission-profile-through-api).

Using REST APIs I am able to do that but permission for user is not getting set.

When I check in DocuSign, group is having correct permission set but same is not set for a user. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Additional Information: This is the request I am sending

```
{
    "newUsers":[{                       
            "email":"'.$email.'",                       
            "userName":"'.$userName.'",
            "password":"'.$password.'",
            "groupList": [{
                    "groupId": "'.$groupId.'",
                    "groupName": "'.$groupName.'",
                    "permissionProfileId": "'.$permissionId.'"
                    }]
            }]
}
```

Also, when a user is added to a group, permissions set at group level will be applied to the users. Is there something missing?

Comment: Can you please add the request on which you are sending to DocuSign for additional troubleshooting?

Comment: As Andrew states, please post your raw request or at least the JSON you are sending out so people can inspect.  Very hard to tell based on what you've posted...

Comment: Edited the question. Included the request in JSON format. Let me know if any other information required.

Comment: Hello, assigning permission profiles to specific users will be available in the upcoming releases of the DocuSign experience and API's. Currently, if you assign a permission profile to a group, and then create a new user (assigning the user to the group with a certain permission profile ID), the individual permission settings for the permission group will be applied to the user, however you will not see that specific group called out in the Users table. If you open the user and look at their permissions, the same ones as specified in the permission profile for the group should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a permission profile you use this endpoint:

`POST {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/permission_profiles`

the response body for that endpoint should contain this info ( I omitted some details from the response)

```
{
  "permissionProfileId": "sample string 1",
  "permissionProfileName": "sample string 2",
  ...
}
```

Once you have the permissionProfileId and permissionProfileName you should be able to assign that permission profile to a user using this endpoint:

`PUT {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/users/{userid}`

and using the permissionProfileId and permissionProfileName in your request (I used dummy values here):

```
{
    "permissionProfileId": "12345",
    "permissionProfileName": "SomeName"
}
```

I hope that helps!

-Yadriel