# How do I set a Permission Set for a user via API

Tags: docusignapi

I want to do exactly what the UI does here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsOM6.png

By default in the UI you can select one of: DS Admin, DS Sender, or DS Viewer

I have not been able to find documentation on how do to this via API.

I found a similar question here: 
[Add permission profile through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409781/add-permission-profile-through-api)
but the marked answer says to assign a user to a group first, and then assign permissions to that group. I want to assign the permission set to a user directly without going through the group. Nor do I want to assign each individual permission setting using the accountSettings parameter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. Please check the best answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what the UI is doing by using the API logger. Either use the regular DocuSign API logging facility (google for it) or you can use the [Beta Recipe Tool which includes a more convenient API logger](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python).

The logger shows all API interactions including those between the DocuSign Web App and the platform. Unfortunately you may find that the Web App is using the "vdev" API that is only available to DocuSign-developed tools.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at what the web app is doing by using chrome dev tools and looking at the network calls. The web app is calling an API that is not documented, which I assume is the vdev API. I would rather not use undocumented APIs also. Do you have any other suggestions for how to figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately the vdev methods are not available since your client_id (integration key) is not valid for them. I don't know of a solution for you at this time. Please edit your question to add information on your use case--why do you want to programmatically change a user's permissions? I will then file it as an enhancement request.